# Export to PDF option is missing in crystal report 8.5

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, reportviewer, export-to-pdf, crystal-reports-8.5

I am using vb6 and crystal report 8.5

The problem which I am facing is that on client machine (window 7 32bit), when I open report there is no option **“Export to PDF”** in export button. While it is running fine and showing “Export to PDF” option on my development machine (window xp).

I have placed the CRXF_PDF.dll, crtslv.dll and register these dll as well but having the same issue.
Please someone help

Comment: You have to distribute several other support files for exporting.  I don't have access to the list of files at the moment, I will post an answer for you later this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the section of my Inno Setup script that pertains to the file export requirements of Crystal Reports 8.5  All you really need to know is the file information, but I'm pasting it as-is:

```
; begin Export Destinations
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\u2d*.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Seagate Software\SI\X86; Flags: sharedfile
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\u2d*.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal; Flags: sharedfile
; end Export Destinations

; begin Export Formats
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\u2f*.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Seagate Software\SI\X86; Flags: sharedfile
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\u2f*.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal; Flags: sharedfile
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\crxf_*.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Seagate Software\SI\X86; Flags: sharedfile
Source: C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\crxf_*.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal; Flags: sharedfile
; end Export Formats

; begin Page Ranged Export
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Seagate Software\Shared\ExportModeller.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Seagate Software\Shared; Flags: sharedfile regserver
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Seagate Software\Shared\crtslv.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Seagate Software\Shared; Flags: sharedfile regserver
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\bin\ExportModeller.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\Bin; Flags: sharedfile regserver
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\bin\crtslv.dll; DestDir: {pf32}\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\Bin; Flags: sharedfile regserver
; end Page Ranged Export
```

I'd appreciate feedback if this solves your problem.